# How to make text popup in a side panel when hover over an image (using modal code)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I currently have a modal that shows information on various images on my page. When I click on an image, lots of information pops up. However, for quick access, I would also like to have an information box on the side quickly show when hovered over. I don't know how to make this work because of how I structured by data.

```
//this displays the information in the modal
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">IMAGE</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-name">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-rarity">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-effect">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-description">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-stack">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-tags">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

//script for getting the information from the modal
<script>
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var Title = button.data('title');
        var Rarity = button.data('rarity');
        var Effect = button.data('effect');
        var Description = button.data('description');
        var Stack = button.data('stack');
        var Tags = button.data('tags');
        var image = button.data('image');
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text(Title);
        modal.find('.modal-rarity').text(Rarity);
        modal.find('.modal-effect').text(Effect);
        modal.find('.modal-description').text(Description);
        modal.find('.modal-stack').text(Stack);
        modal.find('.modal-tags').text(Tags);
        modal.find('.modal-body').html('<img src="' + image + '" alt="' + Title + '" class="center-block">');
    })
</script>
// this is an example item that i would be clicking on (modal works) however, i don't know how to trigger this information to show up in a side panel when hovered over.
<div id="items">
    <!--Tier 1 Offence-->
    <li id="item">
        <!--Barbed Wire-->
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
           data-title="Barbed Wire"
           data-rarity="Common"
           data-description="In Range: Mobs take 50% DPS. Barbed wire will inflict on only one mob at a time."
           data-stack="On Stack: +20% radius and +10% DPS."
           data-tags="barbed, wire, barbed wire"
           data-image="images/items/Barbed Wire.png">
            <img src="images/items/Barbed Wire.png" alt="Barbed Wire" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a JavaScript function that grabs the desired values and concatenates them into one big string which you can output into your sidebar. For each item `<a>` tag, add an `onmouseover=` tag pointing to that function, and an `onmouseleave=` tag pointing to a function or expression to hide the sidebar away again.
To get the value from each of the data tags, concatenate them with some labels and line breaks, and display that in an element with `id="sidebar"` that is previously set to `display: none` or `display: hidden` (in the CSS), you'd set this function in the `onmouseover=` tag:

```
function displayTags() { //there are many other ways to structure this, and this is probably not the most efficient way
    var tags = [];
    tags.push(this.getAttribute("data-title"));
    tags.push(this.getAttribute("data-rarity"));
    tags.push(this.getAttribute("data-effect"));
    tags.push(this.getAttribute("data-description"));
    tags.push(this.getAttribute("data-stack"));
    tags.push(this.getAttribute("data-tags"));
    var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar"); //or whatever you've named your sidebar
    var out = "Title: " + tags[0] + "<br />Rarity: " + tags[1] + "<br />Effect: " + tags[2]; //and so on
    sidebar.innerHTML = out;
    sidebar.style.display = "visible";
}
```

If the function is triggered by an event, the `this` keyword should refer to the element that fired the event.

Then to hide the sidebar away again, you'd put a function like this

```
function hideSideBar() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "none"; //or "hidden", depending on how you want it's presence to affect the layout of the entire page
}
```

Into the `onmouseleave=` on each item `<a>` tag as well.

What I've written may need a bit (a lot) of tweaking to work with what you have, but I think I've made the general idea here clear enough.